# How to rename a file using Mercurial Queues?

Tags: mercurial, mq, mercurial-queue

*Mercurial Queues* is about patches, and patches know nothing about file renames. Is this the reason why Mercurial Queues don't support file renames, or am I doing something wrong renaming the file? I have worked on a patch queue modifying just one file called `foo`. Now I go back to patch 4 and rename the file via `hg mv`:

```
hg qpop 4     # Unapply all patches until patch 4.
hg mv foo bar # Rename file and led Mercuial know about it.
hg qrefresh   # Should apply changes to unapplied patch 4.
hg qpush -a   # Should apply all unapplied patches.
```

I get the following error:

```
unable to find 'foo' for patching
1 out of 1 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file foo.rej
patch failed, unable to continue (try -v)
patch failed, rejects left in working dir
errors during apply, please fix and refresh 5.diff
```

**So how should I do to handle file renames with Mercurial Queues?** Mercurial *commits* handle file renames for a reason (as without, it would lose the whole history about the editing of the file after renaming).

**Update**

Just noticed that `hg histedit` folding changesets and `hg collapse` also lose the information of file renaming, the file shows up as a new one instead of a renamed one, and I guess this is for the same reason. Seems like collapsing private changesets is not possible in Mercurial without loosing that information?

**Update 2**

Found out collapsing private changesets without loosing rename information is possible with `hg rebase` and its `--collapse` option, e.g. `hg rebase -s 5 -d 4 --collapse`. The issue that the other commands should sostain rename information is still vacant, but using the `hg rebase` command there is at least a way to achieve the desired result.

Comment: it looks sort of strange, because `hg help mq` has note about exactly your case: _"By default, mq will automatically use git patches when required to avoid losing file mode changes, copy records, binary files or empty files creations or deletions."_

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the reason why Mercurial Queues don't support file renames,

no.

> or am I doing something wrong renaming the file?

no.

Yes, patches in chain **will have** troubles, if they was prepared for `foo` file, but later in will be `bar`, but due to different reasons: patches are independent, and every and each patch know nothing about changes in others - they work with context, not with sequence of operations in separate patches. You done rename correctly, but this changeset **invalidates later changesets**, prepared on **old content**

Comment: So how should I do to handle file renames with Mercurial Queues?

Comment: maybe (just guessing, can't verify it atm) you could manually create a git styled diff (supports renames), put it in .hg/patches/somename and echo somename >> .hg/patches/series and see if it applies?

Comment: I'll confirm creating a git styled .patch file retains rename information once imported at very least